# I have to find the relationship between Vout and Vin

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, voltage-divider, transfer-function, non-inverting

Can someone use this picture as an example of how to systematically solve/calculate this problem?

My teacher has written terrible, inconsistent notes, and now I'm confused for which formulas to *specifically* use.

[image: homework]

Comment: V out/in is a transfer function and input may include negative feedback ratio with input ratio. (Picture lost)

Comment: Considering the "triangle amplifier" "tries to output a voltage such that the input voltages are equal", what do you get?

Comment: The systematic approach is not to use canned formulas at all, but derive the transfer function from first principles. In this case, the input current of the op-amp is assumed to be zero and the output can be assumed (since there is negative feedback) to drive the two input terminals to the same voltage. If you know how to calculate the voltage on a voltage divider (two resistors) getting the answer should be straightforward. If you make a sincere attempt and show your work, you will get helpful answers if you get stuck.

Comment: From Sphero's comment, apply some voltage from the source (try 2V). Then find the voltage at the non inverting input.

Comment: We assume you know how to compute the voltage drop on one R from current in two Rs

Comment: asking, There are specific formulas (derived from general principles that are much more powerful to master), such as a resistor divider formula with one end grounded. These are easy to use, but they only work in specific cases. For example, the resistor divider might have **both** ends tied to places that are ***not ground*** and there is a slightly more complicated looking formula that is more general and handles that case (and also the grounded-end case.) But even there, it only has so much range. In contrast, there is KCL and KVL which have vast range. Which tools do you want to learn?

Answer (score 3):

It will help to label all the nodes and components:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNp08Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The usual way to approach problems involving op-amps with negative feedback, is to start with the principle that negative feedback causes the op-amp to adjust its output in a way which equalises the potential of its two inputs.

If \$V_P > V_Q\$, then the op-amp output will rise until they are equal, and vice versa. Thus, with negative feedback, the system will always settle in this state:

$$ V_P = V_Q $$

That's one equation which we will need. The second will relate \$V_{IN}\$ and \$V_P\$. Since R1 and R2 form a potential divider between IN and ground we can say:

$$ V_P = V_{IN} \left( \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} \right) $$

This assumes, of course, that no current enters the op-amp's non-inverting input, or is negligible. We'll make the same assumption about the inverting input also.

Next we want to relate \$V_{OUT}\$ and \$V_{Q}\$ which in this case is determined by a similar resistor potential divider consisting of R3 and R4:

$$ V_Q = V_{OUT} \left( \frac{R_4}{R_3+R_4} \right) $$

Now you have three simultaneous equations, which I will leave you to combine to get some equation in terms of \$V_{IN}\$ and \$V_{OUT}\$.

---

Another approach relies on recognising that this is just a regular non-inverting amplifier configuration (blue box), where the input is preceded by a potential divider (red box) which will attenuate the input.

In other words, the red box has a gain, which we already derived above:

$$ V_P = V_{IN} \left( \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} \right) $$

and the blue box has a gain, the classic non-inverting amplifier gain equation:

$$ V_{OUT} = V_{P} \left(1 + \frac{R_3}{R_4} \right) $$

If you solved the simultaneous equation from before, you'll probably immediately recognise that these two equations combine in exactly the same way, to yield the same result.

Comment: thank you so much for the well in depth explanation , i will try work it out.

Answer (score 2):

## How to teach circuits

> My teacher has written terrible, inconsistent notes, and now I'm confused for which formulas to specifically use.

The role of teachers is not to reproduce ready-made knowledge in a formal way because in that case they could be replaced by Google, ChatGPT or other AI. Instead, they should teach circuit ideas in an interesting, engaging, and exciting way so that they get their students to love circuits.

In your case, it is not enough to know the transfer ratio, but also what lies behind it. I suggest that we try to figure it out by building together, step by step, the circuit. This will be just one of the possible scenarios for building the circuit.

## Building the circuit

For some (currently unknown) reason, we have to first attenuate a voltage and then amplify it.

### Voltage divider unloaded

We assemble a *voltage divider* by connecting two resistors (R1 and R2) in series. The resistors have sufficiently high resistances (1 kom) not to overload the input source. Then we apply the input voltage Vin to the entire resistor network and take the voltage drop (VR2) across one of the resistors (the grounded R2) as an output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGIPOb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To derive the transfer ratio, we can first imagine that the input voltage Vin applied to the entire resistance (R1 + R2) creates a current I = Vin/(R1 + R2); then this current flows through the resistor R2 and creates a voltage drop VR2 = I.R2 = Vin.R2/(R1 + R2). Figuratively speaking, we can see two "cascaded" devices in this circuit - a *voltage-to-current converter* (R1 + R2) and *current-to-voltage converter* (R2).

As you can see from the DC simulation above, the output voltage "measured" by the voltmeter corresponds exactly to the calculated one.

### Voltage divider loaded

But if we load the voltage divider output with a (1 k load) RL, the voltage drops. A possible explanation is that the (equivalent) resistance of the lower part of the voltage divider decreases (R2||RL). Another possible explanation is that the current trough R1 increases so the voltage drop VR1 increases and VR2 decreases.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmSgG5.png)</sup>

### Conceptual voltage follower

The problem is that the load may have a relatively low resistance and draw significant current from the divider's output. What should we do to solve the problem?

The formal answer is to include a buffer (voltage follower) between the output of the divider and the load. But we are not satisfied with formal ("terrible and inconsistent") answers, and we want to know what is inside that buffer... what its idea is.

It turns out that this is a great idea, and it is not new, but quite old - somewhere from the middle of the 19th century when they managed to make (without any electronics) an almost "ideal" voltmeter. The name of this idea is "negative feedback". To implement it, we supply the load not by the divider's output but by another varying voltage source Vout and connect a null indicator NI between the divider and load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs3kCe.png)</sup>

Our task is to adjust Vout (from the CircuitLab parameters) so that the null indicator shows 0 V. Then the voltage across the load is equal to the open circuit voltage of the divider. There is no current drawn from the divider's output by the load since it is supplied by Vout. The voltage divider "thinks" there is no load connected; it "sees" an open circuit. This phenomenon has the figurative name "bootstrapping".

### Op-amp follower

Now it remains only to replace the source, the null indicator and the man with an op-amp to get an op-amp follower.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM49JV.png)</sup>

### Conceptual non-inverting amplifier

If we put another 1 k resistor in series with the load, we will be forced to double our output voltage to do the job and the conceptual follower will become an amplfier.
Run the simulation below, first with R3 = 0 and then with R3 = 1 k (and not forget to zero the null indicator).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNAwYz.png)</sup>

### Op-amp non-inverting amplifier

Thus we get the famous *op-amp non-inverting amplifier* (NIA) where the op-amp is forced to double its output voltage to do its job.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEfZSO.png)</sup>

### "Reversed" voltage divider

Finally, we can notice something interesting in the circuit - *it consists of two cascaded voltage dividers*. The first is normal and the second is "reversed"; let's see why.

By varying the input voltage of the second divider (the op-amp output voltage Vout), the op-amp sets its output voltage VR4 equal to the input voltage of the non-inverting amplifier (which is the output voltage Vd of the first divider). So, in fact, the input and output of the second divider are swapped.

Our conclusions are:

- *****The circuit consists of two cascaded voltage dividers - ordinary and "reversed".*****
- *****The op-amp inverting amplifier can be thought as a "reversed voltage divider".*****

## Applications

### Op-amp differential amplifier

Perhaps you are already asking yourself the question, what is the point of such a circuit that first attenuates and then amplifies the input voltage?

A very popular application of this configuration is in the circuit of an *op-amp differential amplifier* where it is used to equalize the gains of the inverting and non-inverting inputs. Run the time-domain simulation below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqZOpI.png)</sup>

First set equal offset ("common-mode") input voltages of 2 V. Then add 1 V AC (differential) input voltage...

- to Vin1

[image: Graph_1]

- to Vin2

[image: Graph_2]

As you can see, the gains of the two inputs are the same and equal to 1.

Comment: thank you so much for the well in depth explaination that made a lot more sense than any of the boos ive read before. really appriciate it!

Comment: @asking, I also thank you for the rating. My vocation is to be a teacher, so I was always happy when I received such feedback from my students.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDH7qZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We know that an ideal opamp wants to find:

$$\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-\tag1$$

Using the voltage divider formula we find:

$$\text{V}_+=\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\cdot\text{V}_\text{i}\tag2$$
$$\text{V}_-=\frac{\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\cdot\text{V}_\text{o}\tag3$$

So, using \$(1)\$ we find:

$$\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\cdot\text{V}_\text{i}=\frac{\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\cdot\text{V}_\text{o}\tag4$$

Using your values, we get:

$$\frac{5}{5+5}\cdot\text{V}_\text{i}=\frac{1}{3+1}\cdot\text{V}_\text{o}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space2\text{V}_\text{i}=\text{V}_\text{o}\tag5$$